# Конкатенация строк в PHP

Tags: php, строки, инспекция-кода

Какая запись выглядит более эстетично, если цель - красивый код?

Такая

```
$user = $this->userName . implode("-", $this->birthDate);
```

Такая

```
$user = $this->userName;
$user .= implode("-", $this->birthDate);
```

Или такая

```
$user = $this->userName;
$birth = implode("-", $this->birthDate);
$user .= $birth;
```

Пример написан от балды, так что строго не судите. По сути, мне интересно только одно - допустимо ли пихать в конкатенацию функции или понятнее когда "конкатенируются" только переменные. Сам склоняюсь к первому варианту.

Comment: вы только эти варианты рассматриваете? есть же куча других, в том числе экзотических )

Comment: Да нет, не только. Меня любые устраивают. Лишь бы были понятны тем, кто будет этот код читать))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Субъективно мне нравится первый вариант, так как в нем одна строка и она укладывается в 80 символов (т.е. удовлетворяет стандарту PSR-2). Третий вариант неплох, вы выделяете $birth в отдельную переменную, однако, как мне кажется $this->birthDate в implode() и так дает достаточно информации, что речь идет о датах рождения. Отторжения или желания переделать ни один из вариантов не вызвал.

Comment: Вот и мне так кажется, что нет смысла плодить строки там, где можно уложиться одной в 80 символов. Но бывают же ситуации, когда надо упаковать в строку больше значений, чем здесь. В таких случаях лучше использовать третий?

Comment: Для более сложных сборных строк можно использовать `$user = sprintf('%s %s', $this->userName, implode("-", $this->birthDate));`

Comment: Можно и второй, к третьему варианту обычно прибегают, когда у вас сложная бизнес-логика и промежуточные результаты не совсем очевидны. В этом случае можно ввести переменную с удачными названием и здорово сэкономить время разбирающему код.

Comment: Ну раз все три варианта имеют право на жизнь, тогда я спокоен) За `sprintf()` спасибо. Не сталкивался еще с ней. Буду пробовать при случае.